# AtTask API complete list of search modifiers

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Where can I find a complete list of the available search modifiers the AtTask API?

The [basic REST documentation](https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/#Search) gives a list of "**some**" of the modifiers.

Which are:

- eq
- ne
- gte
- lte
- isnull
- notnull
- between

  `...percentComplete=50&percentComplete_Mod=gte...`

I've seen reference to other modifiers like, "in" and "notin", on StackOverflow, but I would like to see a complete list.

Can someone provide a complete list of search modifiers?  It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, the modifiers "in" and "notin" don't seem to be working for me. When I try to use them they are ignored.  I'm using version 2.0 of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete list of Qualifiers and what they do can be found in out advanced reporting manual.

https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/217196097-Filter-and-Condition-Modifiers

Example of using in

```
attask/api/task/search?status=CPL&status=INP&status_Mod=in
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the example for using the in modifier.  Other examples I've seen show it using a comma delimited list.

Comment: Link is now broken

Comment: I have updated the link to reflect the correct new site.